# Prove trigonometric inequality with sin

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $ n\in \mathbb{N}^{*},x\in \mathbb{R} $.
Prove that $ sin^{2}(x)\cdot sin^{2}(2x)\cdot ...\cdot sin^{2}(2^{n}x)\leq \left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{n},\forall x\in \mathbb{R} $.
The only result I managed to find is $ |sin^{2}(x)\cdot sin^{3}(2x)\cdot sin^{3}(4x)\cdot ...\cdot sin^{3}(2^{n-1}x)\cdot sin(2^{n}x)|\leq \left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{\frac{3}{2} \cdot n} $.

Comment: Please share your approach